# Running the get calls only for once in gatling

Tags: performance, gatling

I have a scenario where i want to do a get call after running the post-call for give amount of time  and the Get call is only for once after running the POST calls, any suggestions on how to do in Gatling

Comment: Please show your code.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
def basicScn: ScenarioBuilder = scenario("BasicScenario")
.exec(postReq)
.pause(5)
.exec(getReq)

val postReq: HttpRequestBuilder = http("PostRequest")
.post("/hello/world")
.body(StringBody("${body}")).asJson

val getReq: HttpRequestBuilder = http("GetRequest")
.get("/stack/over/flow")
```